# How to create button in kivy using class inheritance from Screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create Kivy buttons dynamically using python code. This worked so far, however now I encountered the situation that I need to create buttons inside a class which inherits from Kivy `Screen`.
Unfortunately this does not add a button to my screen.

Please have a look at my example code below. L. 40 makes problems, if I call the function `add_button()` in the init of the `ExampleScreen` the buttons are added. However, if I call this function in the class which inherits from this Screen, the button is not added (L. 40).

I hope someone can help me or explain why this does not work. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The button is added as a children of the layout  (`print(self.box_layout_button.children)` yields all three button objects), however it is just not visible...

example.py

```py
class ExampleScreen(Screen):

    label_text = NumericProperty(501)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # This works
        def decrement(instance):
            self.label_text -= 1
        self.button = Button(text="Test Button 1")
        self.box_layout_button.add_widget(self.button)
        self.button.bind(on_press=decrement)

        # This works
        self.add_button()

    def add_button(self, label='Test Button 2'):
        def decrement(instance):
            self.label_text -= 1

        self.button = Button(text=label)
        self.box_layout_button.add_widget(self.button)
        self.button.bind(on_press=decrement)



class X01_Game(ExampleScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(X01_Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init(self):
        # This does not add a button
        self.add_button(label='Test Button 3')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
        sm.add_widget(ExampleScreen(name='example_page'))
        sm.current = 'example_page'

        game = X01_Game()
        game.init()

        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

example.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<ExampleScreen>:
    box_layout_button: box_layout_button
    name: 'example_page'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.4
        size: root.size
        id: box_layout_button

        Label:
            font_size: 20
            bold: True
            text: str(root.label_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an instance of `X01_Game`, but not adding it to the `ScreenManager`. Try modifying your `ExampleApp` class like this:

```
class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
        sm.add_widget(ExampleScreen(name='example_page'))
        game = X01_Game(name='game')
        game.init()
        sm.add_widget(game)
        sm.current = 'game'

        return sm
```